# D3 interactive graph - Update graph with new data from server

Tags: javascript, ajax, d3.js, data-visualization

I want to update a graph in D3(or other visualization library in general) as such:

1. user click on an item e.g. a node of the graph
2. new data is returned from the server
3. using the new data, appending new edges and nodes to the old graph
4. possibly changing the attribute of some old nodes, such as making 'B' red in the illustrating diagram below.

This is illustrated in the diagram:
[image: Illustration image - updating a graph]

My question is: how can this be done? With what technology and which steps? I saw in another question on real-time updating that you may use WebSocket. But in my case, it is NO real-time update. So is WebSocket still the proper choice or is there a better choice like AJAX?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are only going to update the graph on user driven events, like click hover etc. then using websockets would be an overkill. WebSockets are used to send data to client, when the client may not know when to update and the server has that information.

So for eg. if you would want to update the graph of another person also, when the someone updates his graph something on the lines of Google Docs, then you need to use WebSockets.

Otherwise, you can use jQuery if it is a single page requirement. If you have a larger project you can use angular, which also has great data binding for D3. But yes, you basically choose AJAX calls and not WebSockets.

Comment: Totally overkill until this graph is not multi-user oriented

Comment: The major thing to update data in such structures to do not re write your collection at whole but extend it. This will prevent you loosing local data of each of graph items and links to them.

Comment: Thank you. It's a single person application, so as you said WebSockets is not the right tool. It will be used with React.